# class not working with variables

Tags: python, class

My code is like this:

```
size = 50
class cube:
    def setsize(sizechoice):
        size = sizechoice
```

However, when I do `cube.setsize(200)` and then `print(size)` It says 50 not 200. Idk what the problem is, I'm new to python and I just learned how classes work so I hope you can help me!

Comment: You've not set it as a class or instance attribute. `size` is just a global variable, nothing to do with the class you've created.

Comment: Please edit your question to fix the indentation and show exactly how you are calling the method

Comment: `size` is a global variable when referenced outside `setsize`, and a local one (that disappears immediately after the method returns) in `setsize`, as you assign to it but never say you want to modify the global one (through `global size`). In no case it's an instance variable - for that, you would need `self.size` (and to get rid of the useless global `size`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
size = 50
```

Here `size` is a global variable; there's only one instance of it and it's the same throughout the whole module.

```
class cube:
    def setsize(sizechoice):
        size = sizechoice
```

Here however `size` refers to a *local variable*, also named `size`, which shadows (hides) the global one. This comes from the fact that Python assumes that if you are inside a function and assign to a variable without explicitly saying that you refer to a global, you want to create a local with that name. So, as it is, if you do

```
c = cube() 
c.setsize(100)
print(size) 
print(c.size)
```

you'll get 50 for the first `print` (as the global `size` won't be affected), and an error on the second one (as you didn't create any instance attribute named `size`).

Now, if you want to explicitly refer to the global `size` you would have to do:

```
class cube:
    def setsize(sizechoice):
        global size
        size = sizechoice
```

so if you do

```
c = cube() 
c.setsize(100)
print(size)
```

it'll print 100; but most probably this is not what you want: an instance method generally is expected to affect instance-specific attributes, not globals - IOW, in this implementation all cubes would have the same size!

```
c = cube() 
d = cube() 
c.setsize(100)
print(size) # prints 100
d.setsize(200)
print(size) # prints 200
# why did I even bother creating two instances?
```

What you probably want is to have a `size` specific of each cube; to do this, you must esplicitly refer to `self.size`, as in Python there's no "implicit `this`" rule (such as in Java, C#, C++, ...). You may also want to provide an easy way to set it on construction, so you should probably do:

```
class cube:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size

    def setsize(self, size):
        self.size = size
```

and get rid of the now useless global `size`.

```
c = cube(100)
d = cube(200)
print(c.size) # 100
print(d.size) # 200
d.setsize(300)
print(c.size) # 100
print(d.size) # 300
```

Finally, you may even get rid of the `setsize` setter: it doesn't add anything useful over straight assigning to the `size` member, and if you want to add validation logic on assignment later you can always change `size` to be a property.

Answer (score 1):

I see, that you are really new in Python. Take your time and go thru python class [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Because you are new I wrote simple code, that should work for you. With classes you always initialize class, and with that you get an object.

```
size = 50  # Does not influence the class

class cube:  # Class name

    def __init__(self, size): # Initialization
        self.size = size      # Sets the size of cube

    def setSize(self, sizechoice):  # Set method (sets size of cube)
        self.size = sizechoice

    def getSize(self):              # Get method (gets size of cube)
        return self.size

c = cube(200) # Creation of object cube with size of 200

print(c.getSize())  # Gets the cube size and prints it out
```

I hope it helps :)

Best of luck with future programming.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set size as a class or instance attribute.
To set a class or instance attribute, you need to do this:

```
class cube:

    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 0

    def setsize(self, sizechoice):
        self.size = sizechoice
```

so you have to set class or instance attributes inside the `__init__` method with the `self.` keyword.

Now you can do this:

```
cube = cube()
cube.setsize(200)
print(cube.size)
```

and it would print 200.

I would recommend to change the class name to `Cube` (upper C) or something

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to S.O. @pytusiast. The issue is that you are setting the size locally within that function and anywhere else the value is what it was before.

You can define `size` as a `global` variable:

```
class cube:
    def setsize(sizechoice):
        global size
        size = sizechoice
```

but I'm not sure this is the best way as `size` now is a global variable.